# how to resolve the System.Reflection.TargetParameterCountException in WindowsForms C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, invoke, unhandled-exception, invocationtargetexception

I'm getting the Parameter count mismatch exception.

> Unhandled Exception: System.Reflection.TargetParameterCountException: Parameter count mismatch.

My code part for invoking the MethodInfo base is as below

```
Type customerType = executingAssembly.GetType("LateBinding.Customer");
        object customerInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(customerType);
        MethodInfo method = customerType.GetMethod("printCustomerDetails");
        string customerObject = (string)method.Invoke(customerInstance, new object[0]);
```

I have tried to invoke the below method

```
public string printCustomerDetails(object parameters)
    {
        string CustomerName = "";
        foreach (object customer in parameters)
        {
            CustomerName = CustomerName + " " + customer;
        }
        return CustomerName.Trim();
    }
```

Is there anything I missed to invoke MethodInfo base?

Comment: You should check the parameters of printCustomerDetails method and invoke with same number of arguments.

Comment: Show object declaration please.

Comment: @TAHASULTANTEMURI I have added the code.

Comment: Please try below code.

Answer (score 0):

Method.Invoke second argument require an array but inside your code

```
string customerObject = (string)method.Invoke(customerInstance, new object[0]);
```

The **(new object[0]);** is not returning array.Its **printCustomerDetails**
which return an array.

so you need

```
string customerObject = (string)method.Invoke(customerInstance, Details(0));
```